# android: adding layout file to WindowManager

Tags: android

How can I set a layout file to a `WindowManager` like using `setContentView`? Do I use the context or what? I am a newbie developer so I have no idea how to do that, any idea please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setContentView` can only be called in `onCreate` for that matter.
You should use `Activity`s for setting the same or different resource layouts.

Comment: But what if I want to add a layout file to a floating activity?